# C# - SendKeys GUI Buttons Bug

Tags: winforms, button, user-interface, timer, sendkeys

I've downloaded a spammer program from YouTube, and decompiled it. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimpleSpammer
{
  public class Form1 : Form
  {
    private IContainer components;
    private TextBox textBox1;
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Label label1;
    private LinkLabel linkLabel1;
    private Label label2;
    private LinkLabel linkLabel2;
    private Label label3;
    private Timer timer1;
    private Label label4;
    private TextBox textBox2;
    private Label label5;
    private CheckBox checkBox1;

    public Form1()
    {
      this.components = (IContainer) null;
      base.\u002Ector();
      this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing && this.components != null)
        this.components.Dispose();
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      this.components = (IContainer) new Container();
      this.textBox1 = new TextBox();
      this.button1 = new Button();
      this.button2 = new Button();
      this.label1 = new Label();
      this.linkLabel1 = new LinkLabel();
      this.label2 = new Label();
      this.linkLabel2 = new LinkLabel();
      this.label3 = new Label();
      this.timer1 = new Timer(this.components);
      this.label4 = new Label();
      this.textBox2 = new TextBox();
      this.label5 = new Label();
      this.checkBox1 = new CheckBox();
      this.SuspendLayout();
      this.textBox1.Location = new Point(13, 13);
      this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
      this.textBox1.Size = new Size(259, 20);
      this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
      this.textBox1.Text = "SPAM !";
      this.textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
      this.button1.Location = new Point(13, 39);
      this.button1.Name = "button1";
      this.button1.Size = new Size(75, 23);
      this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
      this.button1.Text = "Start";
      this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
      // ISSUE: method pointer
      this.button1.Click += new EventHandler((object) this, __methodptr(button1_Click));
      this.button2.Location = new Point(197, 39);
      this.button2.Name = "button2";
      this.button2.Size = new Size(75, 23);
      this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
      this.button2.Text = "Stop";
      this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
      // ISSUE: method pointer
      this.button2.Click += new EventHandler((object) this, __methodptr(button2_Click));
      this.label1.AutoSize = true;
      this.label1.Font = new Font("Arial", 8.25f, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte) 0);
      this.label1.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowFrame;
      this.label1.Location = new Point(7, 216);
      this.label1.Name = "label1";
      this.label1.Size = new Size(275, 14);
      this.label1.TabIndex = 3;
      this.label1.Text = "Copyright © 2010 TheDarkJoker94. This is a freeware.";
      this.linkLabel1.AutoSize = true;
      this.linkLabel1.Location = new Point(30, 190);
      this.linkLabel1.Name = "linkLabel1";
      this.linkLabel1.Size = new Size(162, 13);
      this.linkLabel1.TabIndex = 4;
      this.linkLabel1.TabStop = true;
      this.linkLabel1.Text = "http://thedarkjoker94.cer33.com";
      // ISSUE: method pointer
      this.linkLabel1.LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler((object) this, __methodptr(linkLabel1_LinkClicked));
      this.label2.AutoSize = true;
      this.label2.Location = new Point(10, 135);
      this.label2.Name = "label2";
      this.label2.Size = new Size(172, 13);
      this.label2.TabIndex = 5;
      this.label2.Text = "Check my C# Tutorials on Youtube";
      this.linkLabel2.AutoSize = true;
      this.linkLabel2.Location = new Point(30, 151);
      this.linkLabel2.Name = "linkLabel2";
      this.linkLabel2.Size = new Size(242, 13);
      this.linkLabel2.TabIndex = 6;
      this.linkLabel2.TabStop = true;
      this.linkLabel2.Text = "http://www.youtube.com/user/TheDarkJoker094";
      // ISSUE: method pointer
      this.linkLabel2.LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler((object) this, __methodptr(linkLabel2_LinkClicked));
      this.label3.AutoSize = true;
      this.label3.Location = new Point(10, 171);
      this.label3.Name = "label3";
      this.label3.Size = new Size(91, 13);
      this.label3.TabIndex = 7;
      this.label3.Text = "More Software on";
      this.timer1.Interval = 500;
      // ISSUE: method pointer
      this.timer1.Tick += new EventHandler((object) this, __methodptr(timer1_Tick));
      this.label4.AutoSize = true;
      this.label4.Font = new Font("Arial", 9.75f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte) 0);
      this.label4.Location = new Point(13, 73);
      this.label4.Name = "label4";
      this.label4.Size = new Size(88, 16);
      this.label4.TabIndex = 8;
      this.label4.Text = "Timer Interval:";
      this.textBox2.Location = new Point(102, 72);
      this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
      this.textBox2.Size = new Size(89, 20);
      this.textBox2.TabIndex = 9;
      this.textBox2.Text = "100";
      this.label5.AutoSize = true;
      this.label5.Font = new Font("Arial", 9.75f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte) 0);
      this.label5.Location = new Point(197, 73);
      this.label5.Name = "label5";
      this.label5.Size = new Size(77, 16);
      this.label5.TabIndex = 10;
      this.label5.Text = "miliseconds";
      this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
      this.checkBox1.Checked = true;
      this.checkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
      this.checkBox1.Font = new Font("Arial", 9.75f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte) 0);
      this.checkBox1.Location = new Point(13, 103);
      this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
      this.checkBox1.Size = new Size(151, 20);
      this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 12;
      this.checkBox1.Text = "Send the ENTER key";
      this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
      this.AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6f, 13f);
      this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
      this.ClientSize = new Size(284, 239);
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.checkBox1);
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.label5);
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.textBox2);
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.label4);
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.label3);
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.linkLabel2);
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.label2);
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.linkLabel1);
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.label1);
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.button2);
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.button1);
      this.Controls.Add((Control) this.textBox1);
      this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
      this.MaximizeBox = false;
      this.Name = "Form1";
      this.ShowIcon = false;
      this.Text = "SimpleSpammer";
      this.ResumeLayout(false);
      this.PerformLayout();
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
      Process.Start("http://thedarkjoker94.cer33.com/");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
        this.timer1.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBox2.Text);
        this.timer1.Start();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        int num = (int) MessageBox.Show("An Exception was thrown!\n" + ex.Message, "ExceptionThrown");
      }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (this.Focused)
        return;
      SendKeys.Send(this.textBox1.Text);
      if (this.checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
      Process.Start("http://www.youtube.com/user/TheDarkJoker094");
    }
  }
}
```

Now, as you can see his code contains a delay field, a text field, and "Start"/"Stop" buttons.

So I've tried to make something similar, and here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Spammer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int delay, y = 1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            delay = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            timer1.Interval = delay;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        private void send()
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Focused)
            {
                return;
            }
            SendKeys.Send(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I've posted a similar question yesterday but this one is far more accurate.

In his program, I've entered some text, chose a delay of 10MS and started it. After a few seconds of sending, I've clicked the "Stop" button in his program and it stopped sending keys immediately.

Now... When I ran my program, and started sending keys (with a 10MS delay), I let it run for a few seconds, and then I pressed "Stop". Nothing happened, and "Stop" didn't even click. It just has shown a blue frame around it and I wasn't able to click it.

And of course, because of this, it didn't stop sending keys.

So, why did it work perfectly in his program but it doesn't work at all in my program?

Comment: My first thought is 10ms is too fast, and the timer is running constantly without giving the rest of your message loop a chance to respond. Does the problem still happen if you use 100ms delay instead of 10? Not sure why your program is different than his though...

Comment: Maybe it's very fast, but fact is that it works perfectly on his program.

I've also tried doing Form1.Focused, but it said that object reference is required...